# MPICH2 error - Credentials for <user> rejected connecting to <host> Aborting: Unable to connect to <host>

Tags: windows, mpich

I need to get MPICH2 working for my college project. But it appears I won't implement anything until I manage how to start MPICH2. For now I only try to run anything on my computer, nothing more. What I do:

I install the MPICH2 (from mpich.org/downloads, from the bottom of the site - the x86_64 Windows version) on my 64bit Windows 7 (I also tried the same with my 64bit Windows 8). I start the installer from a command line (run as an administrator), install MPICH2 for everybody (although my acc is the only one). After successful installation I run the wmpiregister.exe, where I type Danioss (it's the name of my account) and the password for this account. I click register, everything seems to be fine so far. Then I run wmpiconfig.exe, I don't change nor click anything and there is this error:

'g-pc: MPICH2 not installed or unable to query the host'

I can see on the left the table with my host name (g-pc) and the version of MPICH - 1.4.1p1. So it sees it is installed here but cannot query the host. I have no idea what that means.

Of course I tried to execute any compiled program but after running wmpiexec.exe, choosing the file and clicking Execute - I get

'Credentials for Danioss rejected connecting to g-PC
Aborting: Unable to connect to g-PC'

I tried running every .exe as an administrator, didn't help. I also installed and reinstalled the whole MPICH2 tens of times (literally - tens) trying different configurations. I also tried to install the 32bit version but that made no progress. I really have no idea what the problem is.

Please, help me!

Greetings,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Try not specifying username after running wmpiexec -register. Just password for your current user. That worked well for me. Source: https://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/ticket/1151

Answer (score 1):

First: crate a windows user password of your windows user acount

Second: go to installdir deform (C:\Program Files\SFTC\DEFORM\v10.2\3D)

Third: execute "wmpiregister.exe" and register user name and password that your windows user name and password

start deform on multiprocessor

good work

Answer (score 0):

You need to run wmpiregister.exe which is in bin folder, to register your Windows user.

Comment: Try reading the whole text next time. But anyway, I moved to MS-MPI so this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Register using `mpiexec -register` with `".\"` before the username, in your case: `.\Danioss`.